# Orika mapper when one of the properties is an enum that has different supported values for the two classes

Tags: java, orika

I have an object say `Source` that has fields like;

```
firstName,
lastName,
type   (enum with possible values as "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE")
..
..
```

I have another object `Dest` that has fields like;

```
firstName
lastName
type   (enum with possible values as "RED", "GREEN", "PURPLE")
..
..
```

I want to copy `Source` into `Destination` and using `Orika` for that

```
MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
Dest dest = mapper.map(src, Dest.class);
```

Now when `src.getType=BLUE`, then, I get `MappingException` because type in `Dest.class` does not support `BLUE` value.

I do not have an option to change the values supported by the enums for the two classes. But at the same time, I need to find a way to be able to copy over the values of other properties. I need a way so it can ignore copying over value for `type` (that gives a mapping exception for a value that is not supported by the other enum) and still copy over the other values. I tried using "exclude" but it doesnt really resolve the issue. Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you check & confirm the solution I provided!! I value your feedback on it!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom converter focused on `Enum <-> Enum`;

```
public class CustomEnumConverter extends CustomConverter<Enum, Enum> {

    public boolean canConvert(Type<?> sourceType, Type<?> destinationType) {
        return sourceType.isEnum() && destinationType.isEnum();
    }

    public Enum convert(Enum source, Type<? extends Enum> destinationType, MappingContext context) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(destinationType.getRawType(), source.name());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then register it to `mapperFactory` via;

```
ConverterFactory converterFactory = mapperFactory.getConverterFactory();
converterFactory.registerConverter(new CustomEnumConverter());
```

Therefore I can do this;

```
ObjA src = new ObjA();
src.setColor(ObjA.EnumA.BLUE);
ObjB dest = mapper.map(src, ObjB.class);
System.out.println(dest); // prints out ObjB(color=null)

src.setColor(ObjA.EnumA.GREEN);
dest = mapper.map(src, ObjB.class);
System.out.println(dest); // prints out ObjB(color=GREEN)
```